# Returning a file path from webservice and opening it in a new window

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I'm just trying to return the file path to the newly created PDF and open it in a new window.

When I run this code, I open a window that is 404 and goes to `/null` page. I'm assuming this means that I am being returned a null value from the `CreateLabelPdf` C# code.

Does anyone know why I am being returned null and how to fix it?

Javascript

```
function createLabelPdf(sampleIds, line1, line2, line3, loginMatrix, labelStart) {
    var labelInfo = new Object();
    labelInfo.sampleIds = sampleIds;
    labelInfo.line1 = line1;
    labelInfo.line2 = line2;
    labelInfo.line3 = line3;
    labelInfo.labelType = loginMatrix;
    labelInfo.startingLabelPosition = labelStart;


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DesktopModules/DataManagement/TestService.svc/CreateLabelPdf",
        data: JSON.stringify(labelInfo),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
           window.open(data.d);

        }   
    });
}
```

C# Service

```cs
[OperationContract]
public string CreateLabelPdf(List<string> sampleIds, string line1, string line2, string line3, string labelType, int startingLabelPosition)
{
    List<LabelContent> labels = new List<LabelContent>();


    foreach (var sample in sampleIds)
    {
        LabelContent labelContent = new LabelContent();
        labelContent.Line1 = line1;
        labelContent.Line2 = line2;
        labelContent.Line3 = line3;

        labelContent.LabelId = sample;

        labels.Add(labelContent);
    }

    Creator creator = new Creator
    {
        IncludeLabelBorders = false
    };


    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");

    creator.PrintLabels(labels, new Avery5160(), path, startingLabelPosition);

    return path;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting `data.d`?  If you are just returning a string then it should just be `window.open(data)`.

Comment: @Ballbin When I have just `data` it opens `www.website.com/[object Object]` into the new window. I'm assuming that means I am being return a object with just `data` and a string/null with `data.d`

Comment: Run debug on your C# code and check what `path` is being set to right after the assignment and then what it's value if after the `creator.PrintLabels` function.  The other is to use the developer tools with the browser to see what is in the object that was returned.  Are you sure there is a property `d` in the `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. I debugged the code and found out that the error was in this line:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");
```

It was getting a null reference error so I changed the code to:

```
string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");
```

That worked but then I needed to return the relative string to the browser instead of the physcial path so I threw in:

```
string relativePath = @"\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\0.pdf";
return relativePath;
```

Ending code looking like:

```
string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");

creator.PrintLabels(labels, new Avery5160(), path, startingLabelPosition);

string relativePath = @"\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\0.pdf";
return relativePath;
```